# What does the ~ mean in a file path?

Tags: filenames

What does the `~` mean in an absolute file path?

I see this in the output of things like build scripts but the path does not exist.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Isn't Windows [the default](http://gs.statcounter.com/#os-ww-monthly-201410-201509) dice-roll?

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/a/1666770 and [short-vs-long-names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#short-vs-long-names)

Answer (score 38):

Normally it means the user's home directory e.g. `~mike/` would be the user `mike`'s home directory, `~/` would be your own home directory. However, it is unclear to me whether `~/` and `~mike/` should be considered absolute or relative; it seems to depend on the definition given (if anyone can come up with an authorative reference, please post a comment).

Note that I'm talking about Unix based systems here.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory#Unix

Comment: They are absolute, because they are synonyms for absolute paths: on UNIX, the absolute path can be inferred from the contents of the `/etc/login` file.  The expansion is traditionally done by the shell, but any language that has pretensions to be "scripting" will do this as well.

Comment: +1: I didn't know about the `~username/` thing.

Comment: Interestingly, Windows PowerShell also accepts `~` as a synonym for the user's home directoy.

Comment: Jeffery Snover has said that PowerShell was originally based around VIM/EMACs

Comment: @Charles Stewart arguably at least ~/ is relative as it depends on the users context. Also some references define a absolute path as one given from the root of the filesystem, which these obviously aren't. If you have a reference for your statement, please share!

Comment: @Adrian: You can create a file called `~` in your current directory: try `touch "~"` and then `ls`.  Tilde expansion happens before anything that manipulates paths gets hold of what you type into the shell: try `echo ~`.  The latter gives an absolute path.

Comment: @Charles Stewart, I'm not sure what you're point is. ~/ isn't relative to the current directory, but it is relative to the home directory (normally /home, but I guess it could be /users or similar). It all depends on your definition of absolute and relative.

Comment: @Adrian: The definition is from POSIX (see [Pathname resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html#tag_21_04_12) from the current standard).  There's nothing particularly absolute about absolute pathnames: because of chroot, the path /bin for a process might resolve to a different directory than it would for its parent.

Comment: @CharlesStewart, The definition is [from the wild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description), not POSIX.

Answer (score 27):

Actually, both of the answers by Adrian Mouat and studiohack are true.
In operating systems with limited naming convention (Older version of Windows/DOS etc') it signifies a long name.

```
e.g. "c:\program files\" is equivalent to "c:\progra~1\"
```

In some operating systems (namely Unix) it means home-dir (and might be seen as an absolute but not canonical path).
`e.g."/a/vol01/usr/mike/"  might be shortened to "~/mike/"`
* where 'usr' is the home dir.

Comment: In the context of build scripts, it is probably the Unix-centric version.

Comment: Unix paths usually use forward-slashes rather than backslashes.

Comment: @torbengb, true...opps

Comment: A small correction to Xenorose's otherwise excellent answer. File names like "progra~1" are not for older OSs. My Windows 7 system still uses them. (Do dir /x to see.) This is a legacy feature that supports old software that doesn't know about the long file names in modern systems. Old software thinks all filenames follow the [8.3 convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). When a file name doesn't work with this convention, the file system automatically [creates](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982) a second, 8.3 compatible name.

Answer (score 13):

> On many file systems, a file name will contain a tilde (~) within each component of the name that is too long to comply with 8.3 naming rules.

Source: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces - Short vs. Long Names - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx)

(Part-way down the page...)

Comment: Hmm, doesn't quite work for names that contain dots. (e.g. `192.168.1.1` or `somefile.namewithdot`)

Answer (score 6):

And if you do ASP.NET programming it means the top level of the website; rather than navigating using ../../images/some_image.jpg (and getting your nesting level wrong!) you can simply say ~/images/some_image.jpg

Comment: `/images/some_image.jpg` should take you to the root of any web site.  What additional functionality does the tilde provide in ASP.NET?

Comment: ~ takes you to the web application root which is not the same as the web site root if you're using a virtual directory.  For example, if your website is installed on myserver in virtual directory myapp, ~/images/myimage.jpg will resolve to http://myserver/myapp/images/myimage.jpg.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

More about Windows:

1. If hidden file name starts with '~' then Windows Explorer process it as system hidden file. More info in [Why are hidden files with a leading tilde treated as super-hidden?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170526-00/?p=96235)
2. If short file/directory name contains '~' (like "c:\ololoo~1") it is possible for corresponding long name of this file/directory to exceed maximum length (MAX_PATH=260). Developers should workarond this with "\\?\" prefix (even on newer Windows 10 as user can disable ">260"-long paths support with `LongPathsEnabled` registry parameter or with "Enable NTFS long paths" group policy). Example for this workaround using C# can be found in [ZetaLongPaths library sources](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths/blob/cdee92eaf72dfec01bd48236c490eabe589521de/Source/RuntimeNetCore/ZlpIOHelper.cs#L1846).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple of hints that can help you to figure it out better:

```
$ readlink -f ~

$ echo $HOME
```

Note: `$` is a convention to specify the user command line prompt, it is not a part of the commands.

Comment: 'readlink' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: @vtest that's because the example in this comment is for unix-based systems, not Windows.